# How to pass custom options from widget form to widget update callback?

Tags: plugin-development, widgets

I've added a few checkbox options to the default widget form. But I'm stuck on how to access these option states and pass them along during the widget save event (`widget_update_callback`) so that they can be saved by WP to the DB.

How do I pass my custom form values to WP to save as widget options for each widget?

In the first function, I'm Appending my checkbox options to all widgets control panels...

```
add_filter('in_widget_form', 'wse_widget_context_form');

function wse_widget_context_form(){

$checked = ' checked="checked"';
?>
<div class="wse_context">
    <ul>
        <li>Don't show this widget on: </li>
        <li><label><input value="on" type="checkbox" name="noHome" id="noHome"<?php if(isset($instance['noHome'])) echo $checked ?> />Home Page</label></li> 
        <li><label><input value="on" type="checkbox" name="noPosts" id="noPosts"<?php if(isset($instance['noPosts'])) echo $checked ?> /> Posts</label></li>
        <li><label><input value="on" type="checkbox" name="noPages" id="noPages"<?php if(isset($instance['noPages'])) echo $checked ?> /> Pages</label></li>
        <li><label><input value="on" type="checkbox" name="noCats" id="noCats"<?php if(isset($instance['noCats'])) echo $checked ?> /> Categories</label></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Callback function is below. `$instance` doesn't contain the custom form values, only the default widget values (text and content). How do I append my custom options to `$instance`?

```
<?php
add_filter('widget_update_callback', 'wse_widget_context_callback');

function wse_widget_context_callback($instance){
    echo 'instance: '.$instance.'<br/>'; // returns array but no custom form values

}
```

Comment: What widget are you dealing with?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you're still struggling with this, but for anyone that is, here's the solution:

Add the following arguments to `wse_widget_context_form()`: `$widget`, `$return` and `$instance`

Then use the following to get field IDs and field names: `<?php echo $widget->get_field_id('field_name'); ?>` and `<?php echo $widget->get_field_name('field_name'); ?>` respectively. e.g.

```
<li><label><input value="on" type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $widget->get_field_name('noHome'); ?>" id="<?php echo $widget->get_field_id('noHome'); ?>"<?php if(isset($instance['noHome'])) echo $checked ?> />Home Page</label></li>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are dealing with same functionality with http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-context/

you can check it out for the structure of code on how it does

I hope this give idea and help